# Extract Date and Time from string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date, time

I have a string like `asdasd 18.06.2013 07:57`
the following code return the date and time (*18.06.2013 07:57*) well, but i hope there is more clean solution to do this

```js
report_t=$('#reportResult h2:nth(0)').text().match(/[\d]+/g);
$('#output').val(function(){
    return report_t[0]+"."+report_t[1]+"."+report_t[2]+" "+report_t[3]+":"+report_t[4];
}
```

**There is a clean solution to do that!?**

**UPDATE**
I found a solution:

```
/[0-9].+/g
```

and *Jack* has one too. Thak You!

```
/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/g
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: yes. there is with bold as update if not clean..

Comment: Do you mean you want to view the date in this format:
asdasd 18.06.2013 07:57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the matching inside the expression:

```
/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/g
```

Then, each match will contain the whole date/time block.

```
> 'asdasd 18.06.2013 07:57'.match(/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/g)
["18.06.2013 07:57"]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var t=$('#reportResult h2:nth(0)').text();
var String2Date=new Date(t);
```

Comment: the result is "`Invalid Date`" in Greasemonkey and jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/UxrpS/

Answer (score 0):

```
t=$('#reportResult h2:nth(0)').text().split(' ');
$('#output').val(function(){
   return t[t.length-2]+" "+t[t.length-1];
});
```

Comment: seems to be over-complicated and not so resource-friendly, but can be a solution. thx!